# Is it possible to optimize correlation coefficient under linear constraint?

Tags: correlation, optimization, linear-programming, constrained-optimization

I am new to optimization and recently bump into a problem where I have to optimize the correlation coefficient of a series of values with the absolute value of another vector under the linear constraint, but I am not sure if optimization correlation is possible and stable? If it is, should it be seen as nonlinear programming or quadratic programming? Any package recommendation in R?

Additional information:
I have a vector **B** which is given,for example :\begin{bmatrix}25&7&0.2&5.8&1.17&0.25\end{bmatrix}
I also have a matrix **A** which is also known:

\begin{bmatrix}0&1&-1&0&0&0\\-1&0&2&0&1&1\\1&0&-1&0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}

The vector **V** is unknown and the input value should have both positive and negative values:\begin{bmatrix}v1\\v2\\v3\\v4\\v5\\v6\end{bmatrix}

The linear constraint will be:

**A** **V**=**0**

The objective function is to maximize the correlation of the **absolute value** of vector **V** with vector **B** under the constraint that **A** **V**=**0**

Thank you!

Comment: How would you write the correlation in matrix form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to maximize [Pearson's correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), it seems to be a unconstrained optimization problem with linear objective function, linear equality constraints and one quadratic equality constraint that can be solved using the [BFGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm) algorithm.

Instead of considering $B\in\mathbb{R}^d$, consider its shifted version

$$b=B-(\frac{1}{d}\sum_{i=1}^dB_i)\cdot(1, \ldots, 1)^T$$

that satisfies $\frac{1}{d}\sum_{i=1}b_i=0$. For that (fixed) $b$, let $w_i=\frac{b_i}{\|b\|_2}$. By definition, Pearsons correlation coefficient of $b$ and an other vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\frac{1}{d}\sum_{i=1}^d v_i=0$ and $\|v\|_2=1$ is simply

$$\text{corr}(b, v)=\sum_{i=1}^d w_i\cdot v_i$$

Particularly, you are looking for $v\in\mathbb{R}^d$ such that

$$\max \sum_{i=1}^d w_i\cdot v_i$$
subject to

$$A\cdot (v+(\frac{1}{d}\sum_{i=1}^dB_i)\cdot(1, \ldots, 1)^T) =0 \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^d v_i = 0 \text{ and }  \sum_{i=1}^d v_i^2 = 1$$

Except for the spherical constraint $\sum_{i=1}^d v_i^2 = 1$, everything is linear. As all constraints are equality constraints, using [Lagrange Multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), this optimisation problem can be re-written to a unconstrained one, which than can be solved using the [BFGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm) algorithm (the R package [optim](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html) seems to have an implementation of this).

Given such a vector $v$ that solves this optimization problem, the shifted vector $V:=v+(\frac{1}{d}\sum_{i=1}^dB_i)\cdot(1, \ldots, 1)^T$ has maximal correlation to $B$ such that $A\cdot V =0$.